# Application Pool crashing after every automatic recycle since upgrade to ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: clr, iis-7.5, asp.net-4.0, application-pool, crash-dumps

After upgrading an ASP.NET solution to 4.0 we have noticed that every time the application pool recycles automatically (every 1740 minutes), exactly 32 seconds later we get an error in the event logs with event ID 5009.

I installed the debugger on the server and ran the analysis tool on the crash dump and below you can see what I got. Can you help me understand what could be the issue? This is happening on 4 different machines (which all happen to be virtual machines). I noticed that there is a "loop" going on in the full call stack (which I spare you here for space reasons), with the following group of calls being repeated over and over:

> clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorkerAlertableHelper+4d     00000000`00000000     00000000`1bb30ba0     00000000`20a0cf60     00000000`00000000
>   clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker+146     00000000`1bb30ba0     00000000`00000001     00000000`01c05970     00000000`00000000
>   clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWait+73     00000000`20a0c0a0     00000000`00000001     000007fe`e4736ca9     000007fe`e4736c2c
>   clr!CLREvent::WaitEx+c1     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000     000007fe`e7e7f960
>   clr!RegMeta::SaveToStream+134     00000000`20a0b740     00000000`1bb30ba0     00000000`dc951994     00000000`76df0e4a
>   clr!WaitForEndOfShutdown+9     00000000`00010000     000007fe`e7804b65     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000
>   clr!Thread::RareDisablePreemptiveGC+490     000007fe`e4a8cca0     00000000`20a0b9f0     00000000`dc951994     00000000`00001200
>   clr!EEHashTableBase,0>::FindItem+5c     000007fe`e4a8cca0     00000000`20a0b9f0     00000000`00000001     000007fe`efbc229b
>   clr!IsCerRootMethod+b1     00000000`00000001     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000     00000000`ffffff98
>   clr!TAStackCrawlCallBack+1e9     00000000`20a0bd90     00000000`20a0b9f0     00000000`20a0bd90     00000000`20a0bd90
>   clr!Thread::MakeStackwalkerCallback+2f     00000000`20a0c2a0     00000000`00000002     00000000`00000002     00000000`20a0c060
>   clr!Thread::StackWalkFramesEx+8d     00000000`1bb30ba0     00000000`1bb30ba0     00000000`1bb30ba0     00000000`00020019
>   clr!Thread::ReadyForAsyncException+197     00000000`76f471ba     00000000`1bb30ba0     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000
>   clr!Thread::HandleThreadAbort+6c     00000000`76def5e4     000007fe`e4da009a     00000000`1bb30ba0     00000000`00000000
>   clr!Thread::HandleThreadInterrupt+7e     00000000`000007c0     00000000`000007c0     000007fe`e79ae71c     000007fe`e4d9f9dc

**Analysis Summary**
  Type Description Recommendation 
  Error In w3wp_*QAWEB4*_PID_*4668*_Date__05_02_2012__Time_04_16_30PM_*242*_Second_Chance_Exception_C0000005.dmp the assembly instruction at clr!CLREvent::WaitEx+f in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll from Microsoft Corporation has caused an access violation exception (0xC0000005) when trying to write to memory location 0x20990ff0 on thread 20
Please follow up with the vendor Microsoft Corporation for C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll

Information DebugDiag determined that this dump file (w3wp_*QAWEB4*_PID_*4668*_Date__05_02_2012__Time_04_16_30PM_*242*_Second_Chance_Exception_C0000005.dmp) is a crash dump and did not perform any hang analysis. If you wish to enable combined crash and hang analysis for crash dumps, edit the Globals.asp script (located in the DebugDiag\Scripts\inc folder) and set the g_DoCombinedAnalysis constant to True.

**Analysis Details**

Report for w3wp_*QAWEB4*_PID_*4668*_Date__05_02_2012__Time_04_16_30PM_*242*_Second_Chance_Exception_C0000005.dmp
Type of Analysis Performed   Crash Analysis 
Machine Name   XXXX01-QA-WEB01 
Operating System   Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2 
Number Of Processors
Process ID   4668 
Process Image   c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe 
System Up-Time   4 day(s) 14:59:36 
Process Up-Time   00:06:32

**Thread 20 - System ID 4364**
Entry point   clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc 
Create time   5/2/2012 4:10:16 PM 
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 0:0:1.421 
Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 0:0:0.453

**.NET Call Stack**

Function 
System.Threading.Thread.SleepInternal(Int32) 
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.TimeSpan) 
Sitecore.Services.Heartbeat.WorkLoop()*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for Sitecore.Kernel.dll 
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object) 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object) 
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) 
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) 
System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

**Full Call Stack**
*removed for space reasons*

**Exception Information**
CLR!CLREVENT::WAITEX+FIn w3wp_*QAWEB4*_PID_*4668*_Date__05_02_2012__Time_04_16_30PM_*242*_Second_Chance_Exception_C0000005.dmp the assembly instruction at clr!CLREvent::WaitEx+f in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll from Microsoft Corporation has caused an access violation exception (0xC0000005) when trying to write to memory location 0x20990ff0 on thread 20

**Module Information** 
Image Name: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll   Symbol Type:  PDB 
Base address: 0x00000003`00905a4d   Time Stamp:  Sat Jul 09 05:44:20 2011

Checksum: 0x00000000`00000000   Comments:  Flavor=Retail 
COM DLL: False   Company Name:  Microsoft Corporation 
ISAPIExtension: False   File Description:  Microsoft .NET Runtime Common Language Runtime - WorkStation 
ISAPIFilter: False   File Version:  4.0.30319.239 (RTMGDR.030319-2300) 
Managed DLL: False   Internal Name:  clr.dll 
VB DLL: False   Legal Copyright:  © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. 
Loaded Image Name:  clr.dll   Legal Trademarks:
Mapped Image Name:     Original filename:  clr.dll 
Module name:  clr   Private Build:  DDBLD205 
Single Threaded:  False   Product Name:  Microsoft® .NET Framework 
Module Size:  9.39 MBytes   Product Version:  4.0.30319.239 
Symbol File Name:  c:\symcache\clr.pdb\887DDF30473443C9905C3217115D7DE72\clr.pdb   Special Build:  &

**Script Summary**
  Script Name Status Error Code Error Source Error Description Source Line 
CrashHangAnalysis.asp Completed

Comment: Is your process beeing profiled? I have seen call stack with RegMeta in their call stacks when a profiler was attached.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "being profiled". How do I check that?

Comment: Do you mean having perfmon running on the same machine, by any chance?

Comment: No I mean a memory or Performance Profiler like YourKit, Ants, or the VS Profiler, ...

Comment: Not to my knowledge. I do have perfmon running continuously on the production servers, but the problem occurs also on the QA server which doesn't have perfmon running

Comment: It looks like Sitecore starts a new thread (for Heartbeat.Workloop) which never exits when w3wp wants it to.

Comment: Franz, have you worked this around? Now I have pretty similar stack in WinDbg and looking for some ideas why it could happen.

Answer (score 0):

What is error code listed in event id 5009 description? http://www.eventid.net/display-eventid-5009-source-Microsoft-Windows-WAS-eventno-8833-phase-1.htm indicates that this might be caused by an empty folder from the previous .Net version.